# Obtain values from a table according to values in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query which returns the id of some items, EJ:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE CAT_ID = 1
```

The query can return 1 or N random values, suppose it returns "1, 3, 4".

Then I must make a second query to the same table but applying the values returned by the first query. Taking the values above, the second query would be as follows (I am using WHERE IN):

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE CAT_ID IN (1, 3, 4)
```

My question is, is there any way to perform this process in the same query? Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. Can you explain more?

Comment: You can use subquery https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparisons-using-subqueries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE CAT_ID IN (SELECT CAT_ID FROM items WHERE {YOUR WHERE CLAUSE LOGIC})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE CAT_ID IN (select CAT_ID  from items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery and join

```
select i.* from items i join
 (select CAT_ID from items where --your condition
 ) t
 on i.CAT_ID=t.CAT_ID
```